# Google Charts: how do I change the percentage label color?

Tags: javascript, api, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to display pie charts. In my options variable, I have the legend set this: `legend: {position: 'labeled', textStyle: {color: 'white', fontSize: 24}}`

Now if you look at the image below, the font color only applies to the label name, but not the percentage text or the label line. Is there anything I can do to change the color for the percentage text and the label line to white?

[image: Pie chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't see an option that will change the text style for the charts elements mentioned
but the chart's svg can be modified manually

however, the chart will revert back to the default style,
whenever there is activity, such as hovering a slice

as such, a `MutationObserver` can be used to override the styles

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y');
    data.addRows([
       ['Moving to a new city', 25],
       ['Meeting new people', 12.5],
       ['Gaining independence', 62.5]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      $.each($('#chart_div path[stroke="#636363"]'), function (index, path) {
        $(path).attr('stroke', '#ffffff');
      });
      $.each($('#chart_div text[fill="#9e9e9e"]'), function (index, label) {
        $(label).attr('fill', '#ffffff');
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    chart.draw(data, {
      backgroundColor: '#1f618d',
      legend: {position: 'labeled', textStyle: {color: 'white', fontSize: 24}}
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, only draw back is when using method `getImageURI` -- the image produced will not include the manual changes...

Answer (score 2):

change the css:

```
g g g text
{
    fill: black;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When providing an answer, it is usually required to explain your answer and how it works to the OP :).

Comment: Sorry I'm new. Google charts define a structure in css. This example change the color gray in the percentage in the css stylesheet. If you have several graphics you can put a class

Comment: This solution helped med get the result I looked for.