# Google Pie chart legend labeled line color

Tags: charts, colors, legend

I have a Google pie chart with the legend position set to labeled. My objective is to make all the text and legend marker lines black. Right now the lines are gray and so are the values-and-percentage numbers. Is there any way to make these all black?

```js
var options = {
    pieHole: 0.5,
    pieSliceText: 'none',
    textStyle:{color: 'black'},
    legend: {position:'labeled', labeledValueText: 'both', alignment:'center',
         textStyle: {
                  color: 'black', 
                  fontSize: 12}, strokeColor: {color: 'black'},  
              },
};
```

[Here is an example of the gray text and line marker I'm trying to make all black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdMKp.png)

Comment: Please provide example code, screenshots, etc., where applicable to help others understand your problem better. If you provide just enough information so that someone can reproduce your problem, you'll be more likely to get an acceptable answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I'll do that!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Mutationobserver is what I needed since Google Charts have no built in commands to change these attributes.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('pie_chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
    chart.draw(view, options, observer);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      $.each($('#pie_chart path[stroke="#636363"]'), function (index, path) {
        $(path).attr('stroke', '#000000');
      });
   $.each($('#pie_chart path[fill="#636363"]'), function (index, path) {
        $(path).attr('fill', '#000000');
      });
      $.each($('#pie_chart text[fill="#9e9e9e"]'), function (index, label) {
        $(label).attr('fill', '#000000');
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
```

And added this to the header.

```js
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Here is the source of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285084/google-charts-how-do-i-change-the-percentage-label-color)